# How can we store a prevState data in to a variable so that if any error occurs during api call we can revert the change that took place

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a toggle button which toggles data after click after which api is called to make necessary changes in databases. So if api ends up with error I wish to revert the changes that took place in UI. How can I achieve this.

currently trying to do like this

```
#global variable
let prevData={}

#Set State
(data)=>{ 
this.setState(prevState=>{
this.prevData=prevState.data
return {
data:data
}}}
```

this if I console log prevData its gives the updated state data instead of prevData

Answer (score 1):

After some searching found that

JSON object can create a detached copy of an object, which then wont change the data as the state changes.

```
this.prevData=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.data))
```

There are multiple ways of creating copies this seems easier to understand.